# Тире как "симметричный" знак?

Tags: пунктуация

> Как стадные животные – дельфины пристально наблюдают друг за другом.
>   Как одарённые возможностями эхолокации – знают про организм больше
>   нашего, несмотря на все ультрасовременные изобретения.

Начала править на запятую, на втором предложении засомневалась...

Понимаю, что второе тире означает пропуск слова (дельфины), а конструкции 1–2, чую, должны быть... созвучными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постановка запятой является **нормой**. Розенталь: Приложение, присоединяемое союзом как (с дополнительным значением причинности), а также словами по имени, по фамилии, по прозвищу, родом и др., обычно обособляется, если стоит в начале или середине предложения (независимо от того, какой частью речи выражено определяемое слово). [XXIV. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ С ОБОСОБЛЕННЫМИ ЧЛЕНАМИ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm)

**В данном случае тире является авторским знаком**, обозначающим увеличенную паузу. И предложения действительно связны –  **параллельной интонацией**.