# Тире перед "это", когда "это" является подлежащим (?)

Tags: пунктуация

Есть две фразы: "Неправильная реклама — это потеря времени. А для нового бизнеса — это начало конца".

В первом предложении тире нужно, а во втором, как мне кажется, нет, поскольку в этом случае "это" играет другую роль в предложении. В правилах не могу найти, обоснуйте, пожалуйста.

Заранее благодарна за помощь:)

Comment: Нашла правило: "Перед словом "это" тире не ставится, если "это" является подлежащим, выраженным указательным местоимением". Во втором предложении примера "это", на мой взгляд, как раз и является подлежащим. Обосновывает ли это правило неправильность тире в предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом предложении "реклама" - подлежащее, "потеря времени" - сказуемое, "это" - указательное местоимение, - тут Вы разобрались.

Второе могло бы выглядеть так:

*А для нового бизнеса это — начало конца.*

Правило:

> При подлежащем, выраженном словом **это**, между главными членами
>   предложения тире ставится в зависимости от логического выделения
>   подлежащего и наличия паузы после него; ср.: *Это — начало всех
>   начал.*

Ваши два предложения составлены симметрично, это авторская воля,

**[они действительно связны – параллельной интонацией.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431907/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA)**

Answer (score 3):

**В полном объеме фраза выглядела бы так:**

Неправильная реклама (вообще) — это (только) потеря времени. А (неправильная реклама) для нового бизнеса — это начало конца".

Здесь явно присутствует **симметричная структура**, поэтому лучше считать ЭТО связкой в обоих случаях, при этом  второе предложение является неполным.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, можно по-другому посмотреть на второе предложение и считать,  что в нем просто пропущены слова "неправильная реклама", а его полная форма:

**А для нового бизнеса неправильная реклама — это начало конца.**

Тогда в сокращенной форме тире стоит на месте выпавшего подлежащего:

**А для нового бизнеса — (это) начало конца**.

Наличие частицы "это" не меняет сути дела.

Answer (score 1):

Тире ставится перед "это", "это есть", "это значит", "вот", если сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже или неопределенной формой, присоединяется посредством этих слов к подлежащему, например:

Коммунизм – это есть Советская власть плюс электрификация всей страны.